# What should I use for i18n in Flutter: S.of(context) or S.current?

Tags: flutter, internationalization

I'm using the `i18n plugin for Flutter` (I believe it's [this one](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10128-flutter-i18n)) that comes with `Android Studio`.

And in every example I see it says to use `S.of(context).my_string` to get the `Strings` but it always returns `null`.

If I use `S.current.my_string`, it seems to work.

So is `S.current` the right way to do it and every doc/tutorial out there is wrong, are they the same or what?

What I'm basically asking here, is what is the difference between them.

Comment: `S.of(context)` works fine for me so I guess it must be another reason. Can you show some code example?

Comment: Nothing really relevant to show. It happens even if I create a new project, add the delegates to MaterialApp, extract an existing String and try using it with S.of(context).my_string fails.

Answer (score 3):

Seems like `S.of(context)` is initially available way to access localised string.

But sometimes you need to use it without Build Context (in ViewModel, for example). So `S.current` was added for these cases.

More info [here](https://github.com/long1eu/flutter_i18n/pull/50)

Answer (score 1):

**S.of(context)** and **S.current** are both used to access the translated strings defined in a localization delegate.

**S.current** is a static reference to the current localized resources. when we don't have context easily available or **can't access BuildContext** that case S.current can be used.

**S.of(context)** is a method used to access localized resources **based on provided context**.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint for everyone who faces a problem with using S.current: S.current takes some time to load translations and will return default language till the translation is fully loaded. So if you assign S.current before widget built is completed, your widget will show default language translation even though all other S.of(context) usages will be correct translated values.

If there is no workaround for you other than using S.current, make sure you have a wait block in front of custom function and then you can assign value. For example:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadInitialLocale();
  }

String stringVarTryIt = 'Try It';
void _loadInitialLocale() async {
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 5));
    stringVarTryIt = S.current.stringVarTryIt; // will have correct translated value
  }
```

Comment: Do you have a doc that talks about it?

Comment: Here is the official guide about i18n: https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/accessibility-and-internationalization/internationalization .However Flutter Intl for VS Code has better doc and makes it way easier to use: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=localizely.flutter-intl